# How to set correct value for Django ROOT_URLCONF setting in different branches

Tags: python, django, mercurial

I've put site directory created by `django-admin startproject` under version control (Mercurial). Let's say, the site is called `frobnicator`.

Now I want to make some serious refactoring, so I clone the site using command

```
hg clone frobnicator frobnicator-refactoring`
```

but `ROOT_URLCONF` in `settings.py` still says `frobnicator.urls`.

Is there a better way to overcome this problem rather than moving the site in a wrapper directory and storing this directory under version control (to maintain the same site name after branching) or using local branches?

Comment: How is this a problem?  You always have to update string values in your settings.  Why should this setting be any different?  What "better" are you imagining?  Which strings are being revised automagically?

Comment: No, but maybe some way to compute the value dynamically. Why isn't it computed by default?

Comment: "computed by default"?  By Mercurial's clone command?  How would Mercurial know (a) Python, (b) Django and (c) that you wanted it changed, not copied as it was?

Comment: It can be computed by Django.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply remove project name from the `ROOT_URLCONF` definition - it is optional. Then you can have project folders with different names.

Comment: Yes, it works indeed! I should've try this first before posting the question!

Comment: Yes, I've never understood why the Django docs seem to recommend hardcoding the name of your project directory in your settings, when it is simply not necessary.

Comment: Carl: because once you graduate past very simple/introductory projects, it's unlikely that you'll have such a thing as a "project directory", or URLs inside it.

Comment: James: How is that a reason for the Django introductory docs to recommend (and demonstrate) hardcoding the name of a project directory into your settings?