# Django-registration - error No module named urls

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-registration

I am trying this with Django 1.4 on Windows 7 with the default web server.
The site starts with no errors. but when I browse to localhost:8000
I get the following error

```
ImportError at /
No module named urls
```

I see where the error comes from

It is in the main URLs.py file - (r'^admin/', include('django.contrib.admin.urls')),

If I remove that form URLs.py file the home page comes up. I don't see urls.py file in "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin" folder. So, the error makes sense.

But that line has to be there to get Django-Registration package working. All the blogs I read about has that line. How do I get pass this? Thanks so much for your error.

Fixed the url.py per Siva's instructions below. but no luck.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from SOWLAPP.views import *
from CATALOG.views import *
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'SOWL.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^SOWL/', include('SOWL.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url (r'^user/(\w+)/$', user_page),
    (r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
    (r'^catalog/$', home),
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        { 'document_root' : 'C:/SHIYAM/Personal/SuccessOwl/SOWL0.1/SOWL/SOWL/static'}),
    (r'^admin/', include('django.contrib.admin.urls')),
    (r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),
    (r'^$', main_page),
)
```

Regards,
SHM

Comment: What is the value of ROOT_URLCONF variable in settings.py ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `ROOT_URLCONF` entry in your settings file. The following links might help you.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#root-urlconf

[How to set correct value for Django ROOT_URLCONF setting in different branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781211/how-to-set-correct-value-for-django-root-urlconf-setting-in-different-branches)

But Your urls.py looks messy. 2 entries for same url?

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
(r'^admin/', include('django.contrib.admin.urls')),
```

The following entry should comes at the end.

```
(r'^$', main_page),
```

Comment: Hi Siva,I tried what you suggested and I am getting the same error.
Hi User15..., The value of ROOT_URLCONF in settings.py is this.. Would this impact any of the lines in urls.py
ROOT_URLCONF = 'SOWL.urls'

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment out each line inside:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
)
```

if it does not solve the error Than (as I've expected) error in the urls.py imports...

I suspect they are somewhere here:

```
from SOWLAPP.views import *
from CATALOG.views import *
```

Try to render main page without those modules imported in the urls.py

Also please provide your project settings.py config. That is under section INSTALLED_APPS. There might be an app that has no urls.py and something is referring there. But it's last case that may be... (IMHO)

As the second thought you might have the corrupted/changed Django or/and some apps redistributable version... Check if you installed them via automatic scripts. They rarely have serious bugs.